# Pandas: How to club additional columns to last column while reading CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have fixed columns in CSV. I am using read_csv from Pandas. 
But some of the rows have additional column values. I need to combine all the extra columns into last column.

Basically, I am trying to read a CSV, which has special characters ( **,** ) and ( **'** ) in some of the columns, because of which it is splitting up and creating additional columns. Due to this I am getting  **'ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 7, saw 5'.** So I need a way to dynamically convert last/extra columns to last column

For Example, In the following example, the issue is with the last column, which has a mix of , and '.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv = r"""dummy,obj,loc,query
bar,6usrg82hwsa3,a,'select * from abc'
bar,b6usrg82hwsa3,a,'select * from abc'
bar,4g9cgbm813czs,a,'select * from abc'
bar,fhf8upax5cxsz,b,'select * from abc'
bar,cnphq355f5rah,b,'select * from abc'
bar,b6usrg82hwsa3,b,'SELECT LIST(HIGHLIGHT, ',') WITHIN GR...'"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), quotechar="'")
```

This will throw **'Error tokenizing data'**

The expected output is

```
>>> print(df)
  dummy            obj loc              query
0   bar   6usrg82hwsa3   a  select * from abc
1   bar  b6usrg82hwsa3   a  select * from abc
2   bar  4g9cgbm813czs   a  select * from abc
3   bar  fhf8upax5cxsz   b  select * from abc
4   bar  cnphq355f5rah   b  select * from abc
5   bar  b6usrg82hwsa3   b  SELECT LIST(HIGHLIGHT, ',') WITHIN GR...
```

Comment: Your sample working nice if use `usecols=["dummy","obj", "loc", "query"])`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, but I want to make this function generic and dynamic. Hence did not want to specify 'usecols'.

Answer (score 0):

Never use .csv to store your data if your data contains text columns, even if they do not contain comma at that time. In this case, only use it if and only if you strictly know that comma in data cannot be possible. Use tab separation instead or some other file type. You can use the following solution, and it works for your case,

```
def refactor_text(csv):
    my_dict = dict(
        dummy=[],
        obj=[],
        loc=[],
        query=[]
        )
    for i,line in enumerate(csv.split('\n')):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        line_args = line.split(',')
        for i,key in enumerate(my_dict.keys()):
            if not key == 'query':
                my_dict[key].append(line_args[i])
            else:
                my_dict[key].append(','.join(line_args[i:]))
    return my_dict


df = pd.DataFrame(refactor_text(csv))
```

the function refactor_text accepts one parameter as string (csv) you may want to refactor it if you directly access from a file, or for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

This Works : 
Thought im not sure about this for huge datasets.

```
csv = r"""dummy,obj,loc,query
bar,6usrg82hwsa3,a,'select * from abc'
bar,b6usrg82hwsa3,a,'select * from abc'
bar,4g9cgbm813czs,a,'select * from abc'
bar,fhf8upax5cxsz,b,'select * from abc'
bar,cnphq355f5rah,b,'select * from abc'
bar,b6usrg82hwsa3,b,'SELECT LIST(HIGHLIGHT, ',') WITHIN GR...'"""

lengths = []
for line in csv.split('\n'):
    lengths.append(line.count(',') + 1)

n_columns = min(lengths)
rows = []
for line in csv.split('\n'):
    temp = line.split(',')
    row = temp[:(n_columns-1)]
    temp = temp[(n_columns-1):]
    try:
        temp = [string + ',' for string in temp[:-1]] + temp[-1]
        row += [''.join(temp)]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    rows.append(row)
data = pd.DataFrame(data=rows[1:] , columns=rows[0])

print(data)

# dummy            obj loc                                     query
# 0   bar   6usrg82hwsa3   a                       'select * from abc'
# 1   bar  b6usrg82hwsa3   a                       'select * from abc'
# 2   bar  4g9cgbm813czs   a                       'select * from abc'
# 3   bar  fhf8upax5cxsz   b                       'select * from abc'
# 4   bar  cnphq355f5rah   b                       'select * from abc'
# 5   bar  b6usrg82hwsa3   b  'SELECT LIST(HIGHLIGHT '') WITHIN GR...'
```

Comment: Thanks @Parth. This is almost there. But I was looking at a concise solution. Also, with this i see (,) are getting omitted!

Comment: I have fixed this issue. Although i don't see an easier way to this if you don't want to use usecols.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is create one column `DataFrame` with separator not in data like `|` and then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `n` parameter:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv = r"""dummy,obj,loc,query
bar,6usrg82hwsa3,a,'select * from abc'
bar,b6usrg82hwsa3,a,'select * from abc'
bar,4g9cgbm813czs,a,'select * from abc'
bar,fhf8upax5cxsz,b,'select * from abc'
bar,cnphq355f5rah,b,'select * from abc'
bar,b6usrg82hwsa3,b,'SELECT LIST(HIGHLIGHT, ',') WITHIN GR...'"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), quotechar="'", sep='|')
print (df)
                                 dummy,obj,loc,query
0             bar,6usrg82hwsa3,a,'select * from abc'
1            bar,b6usrg82hwsa3,a,'select * from abc'
2            bar,4g9cgbm813czs,a,'select * from abc'
3            bar,fhf8upax5cxsz,b,'select * from abc'
4            bar,cnphq355f5rah,b,'select * from abc'
5  bar,b6usrg82hwsa3,b,'SELECT LIST(HIGHLIGHT, ',...
```

---

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 0].str.split(',', expand=True, n=3).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("'"))
df1.columns = df.columns[0].split(',')
print (df1)
  dummy            obj loc                                     query
0   bar   6usrg82hwsa3   a                         select * from abc
1   bar  b6usrg82hwsa3   a                         select * from abc
2   bar  4g9cgbm813czs   a                         select * from abc
3   bar  fhf8upax5cxsz   b                         select * from abc
4   bar  cnphq355f5rah   b                         select * from abc
5   bar  b6usrg82hwsa3   b  SELECT LIST(HIGHLIGHT, ',') WITHIN GR...
```